# can we get location updates in IOS swift in a regular intervel of time even when app is not running in foreground

Tags: ios, iphone, background, location

I want to get location updates of the user in a regular interval of time even if the app is not running in foreground.

In most of the articles i have read, they said that the OS will forcefully stop or suspend the background service the app have started.

What i need is the app should regularly check the user location and when that location becomes greater than say 10Kms the app should trigger a local notification.

We were able to do the functionality correctly when the app is ran again by the user. But it wont work in background. And if we inegrated it as a background service ,  then it is causing the app to crash. :(

this part caught my attention after a long time of search

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW8

As far as I understood, they say that the OS will wakeup the app to get the current location when it senses a change in location.

But I didnt get any helping tutorial to accomplish the same

These are the tutorials which I refered

[Periodic iOS background location updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042894/periodic-ios-background-location-updates)

[How do I get a background location update every n minutes in my iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application)

[Getting user location every n minutes after app goes to background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235203/getting-user-location-every-n-minutes-after-app-goes-to-background?rq=1)

[iOS Not the typical background location tracking timer issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377750/ios-not-the-typical-background-location-tracking-timer-issue)

[iOS long-running background timer with "location" background mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650139/ios-long-running-background-timer-with-location-background-mode)

What i need is preferably a background service or something which does the job done which check of the current location calculate distance and makes a local notification.

But as far as i know all the background services will be suspended or killed by the OS within some time after the app is gone in background.

Please guys I am desperate, Its been 2 weeks i am on in its tail.

Building the same for Android was a piece of cake actually.

Any help ???

Answer (score 3):

You can get background location updates easily, you need to enable "Location updates" under "Background Modes" section in capabilities.

You also need to request for Always Authorisation and finally add this

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
}
```

Make sure "Location updates" is activated else the above code will lead to a crash.

Also, write the CLLocationManager Delegate Methods in your AppDelegate class as this would increases chances of those methods being called as mentioned on Raywenderlich Background Location tutorial